# Append url to image path NSString?

Tags: iphone

I'm developing an iOS application consisting of a static sqlite database, series of tableviews and tab based detail view where the first view loaded in the detailview is a swipable imageView which loads a series of images.

I've got it working with this code where it looks for the image locally but I'd like to have it load the image from a URL or display a default image if no internet connection is available.

The images are named in the database as (for the example) image.jpg and I'd like all of them to load from the same URL directory (for the example) http://www.someurl.com/images/

Thank you

```
- (UIImage *) imageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

Image  *currentImage = (Image *) [self.images objectAtIndex:index];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[currentImage filename] stringByDeletingPathExtension]] ofType:@"jpg"];

return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

Comment: try to use the `URL` instead of `path` when you try to reach a not local resource.

Answer (score 0):

The process for this is really very simple:

1. Try to download your image data using `NSURLConnection`
2. If successful, create a UIImage from the data
3. If either of the above fails, switch over to your placeholder/built-in image
4. Display the resulting image

I advise you have some sort of placeholder while the image is downloading, since that can take quite a while.

**Don't** bother with reachability; it's not 100% reliable, whereas actually *trying* the download is.

**Avoid** doing this on a background thread or queue. `NSURLConnection` is asynchronous out of the box to make this easier for you. There are a ton of third-party frameworks that try to simplify working with connections if you wish, though.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *urlStr = [@"http://www.someurl.com/images/" stringByAppendingString:[currentImage filename]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Or something like that...

If the image is large or the internet connection is slow, the NSData initialization might take some time. Consider getting the images data in a background thread, or use some existing framework for that like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)